# Chef: create repo with environments and roles

Tags: chef-infra

I'm a bit confused about some issues or concepts related with how to create a chef cookbook with recipes, roles and environments.

I'd like to get a straightforward description of what I'm looking forward to get using chef.

Up to now, I've been able to roughtly create a cookbook where I'm able to install a lot of utils into my target systems.

Currently, I've created this project structure:

```
├───files
│   ├───elasticsearch
│   │   └───scripts
│   └───mongo
├───recipes
│   ├───default.rb
│   ├───deploys.rb
│   ├───elasticsearch.rb
│   ├───firewall.rb
│   ├───java.rb
│   ├───memcached.rb
│   ├───mongodb.rb
│   ├───net-tools.rb
│   ├───s3.rb
│   ├───security.rb
│   ├───selinux.rb
│   └───wildfly.rb
├───spec
│   └───unit
│       └───recipes
└───test
├───metadata.rb
├───knife.rb
└───Berksfile
```

And my commands in order to "commit" changes to chef server are:

```
berks update
berks install
berks upload --upload
```

Up to now, I've been able to work everything around using that. Nevertheless, I need to:

1. Create PROD, QA, TESTING and DEV environments.
2. Split my recipes with roles in order to be able to apply them to a single or several nodes.

So you can figure out I need to use some extra chef features.

So, first of all I've created a repository using `chef generate repo test -r` and this is the structure I'm working about:

```
test
├── chefignore
├── cookbooks
│   ├── example
│   │   ├── attributes
│   │   │   └── default.rb
│   │   ├── metadata.rb
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   └── recipes
│   │       └── default.rb
│   └── README.md
├── data_bags
│   ├── example
│   │   └── example_item.json
│   └── README.md
├── environments
│   ├── example.json
│   └── README.md
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── roles
    ├── example.json
    └── README.md
```

I need some help in order to adapt my previously file/recipes structures to this other one:

1. Should I place all my existing recipes into a same `cookbook`? Should I create several cookbooks?
2. From now on, what does `berkshelf` stand for?
3. Where should I set my custom property values for PROD, QA, TESTING,... how are they applied?
4. When should I create a `cookbook` or create a `recipe` inside one?

Comment: Did you take the tour at https://learn.chef.io ? I'm affraid answering your question here completely would need more than the 30k chars allowed.

Comment: Yes, I know I'm asking a likely large question, but I've not able to figure out reading documentation. It only shows letter but there's any complete example or stuff project over there... Maybe you could provide any repository on github...

Comment: Indeed, learn.chef.io has had a major refactor and doesn't speak about roles and environment anymore :/ May worth joining slack for a more interactive talk, I don't think SO is adapted for this. https://community-slack.chef.io/